# Smart_IP homepage redirect

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, redirection

I have a [multilingual site](http://landberg.at). I am browsing from Holland and with the [Smart_IP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) i am redirecting to the correct language:

`http://landberg.at/nl/` or `http://landberg.at/de/`

My default language is English. But now as user from Holland for example (dutch browser), you are NOT able to switch to the English homepage. This is because the homepage URL in English is `http://landberg.at/` >> Then you are automatically redirect to `http://landberg.at/nl/`

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the [Smart_IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module's mechanism, but I think you should simply solve your problem outside of Drupal: adding an Apache redirection like `Redirect "landberg.at" "landberg.at/en"`. Somewhat brutal but should work...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [IP to Locale](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip2locale) module. I think this module definitely solve your issue.

> IP to Locale provides IP lookup and redirection services for Drupal
>   sites.